# How to Authentication Github using Github Apps with SAML authentication

Tags: python, authentication, jwt, saml-2.0, github-app

My requirement is that I have written a lambda function in AWS for automatically creating a repository in GitHub using the GitHub API and PAT Token authentication.

```
def create_automatic_repo(repo_name):
    query_url = f"https://api.github.com/api/v3/orgs/{org_name}/repos"
    params = {
        "name": repo_name
    }
 
    headers = {
        'Authorization': f'token {secret[secretKey]}',
    }

    response = requests.post(query_url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(params))
    
    print("creating new repository response ", response)
    print("creating new repository response content ", response.content)
```

We successfully created a repo using the Github API with PAT Token. Now we need to change authentication from PAT Token to the Github Apps.

I am trying to authenticate Github Apps using `AppId` and `PrivateKey`. I have generated the `jwt` token with the `jwt` token. I am trying to hit "https://api.github.com/app/installations/installation_id/access_tokens" this GitHub api for getting `access_token`. I am getting a 200 response but it is redirecting to the SAML authentication page.

```
  $ curl -i \
-H "Authorization: token YOUR_INSTALLATION_ACCESS_TOKEN" \
-H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
https://api.github.com/api/v3/orgs/{org_name}/repos
```

This is the curl command I have found in the official document. If I have `access_token`, I can use the GitHub API for creating a repo through a lambda function in AWS.

I am attaching the flow which I have followed for Authentication for Github Apps. Here I am attaching the official document which I have followed : https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/building-github-apps/authenticating-with-github-apps

1. Created Github Apps by giving homepage `url` as GitHub Organization url
2. Installed Github App under the organization level
3. Wrote python code for generating jwt token

Here I am attaching the Python code for generating the JWT token and triggering the GitHub API for `installation_Id`. I am getting 200 responses but it is redirecting to the SAML authentication page.

```
import json
import os
import time
import jwt
import requests
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend

cert_bytes = open(r'first.txt', "r").read().encode()
print("prtinging cert_bytes ", cert_bytes)
private_key = default_backend().load_pem_private_key(cert_bytes, None)
time_since_epoch_in_seconds = int(time.time())

payload = {
    # issued at time, 60 seconds in the past to allow for clock drift
    "iat": time_since_epoch_in_seconds - 60,
    # JWT expiration time (10 minute maximum)
    "exp": time_since_epoch_in_seconds + (10 * 60),
    # GitHub App's identifier
    "iss": 231726,
}

encoded_payload = jwt.encode(payload, private_key, algorithm="RS256")

print("printing encoded_payload ", encoded_payload)

headers = {
    'Authorization': f'Bearer {encoded_payload}'
}

resp = requests.get("https://api.github.com/app/installations/installation_id/access_tokens", headers=headers)

print('Code: ', resp.status_code)
print('Content: ', resp.content)
```

This is the Image which I am redirecting to the SAML Authentication Page:

[image: This is the Image which I am redirecting to the SAML Authentication Page]

I read the GitHub official documentation, and they mentioned that we needed to activate a SAML session to authenticate Github Apps: 
https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/authentication/authenticating-with-saml-single-sign-on/about-authentication-with-saml-single-sign-on#about-oauth-apps-github-apps-and-saml-sso

But I didn't see the option to enable to SSO SAML authentication as mentioned in the document. : https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/organizations/managing-saml-single-sign-on-for-your-organization/enabling-and-testing-saml-single-sign-on-for-your-organization#enabling-and-testing-saml-single-sign-on-for-your-organization

This is the Image where I did not find option for enabling the SAML Authentication:

[[image: This is the Image where i did not find option for enabling the SAML Authentication]]

Can you please help us on enabling SAML authentication for accessing Github Apps Authentication Process without PAT Token or is there any other way for GitHub authentication from lambda function  in `aws` using GitHub api's apart from PAT Token.